# Why is CSS translate3d transform behaving as relative positioned element?

Tags: css, css-position, translate3d

In the below fiddle, `<a>` tag LOGO is absolute positioned within a `layoutDiv` div which is having `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` CSS being applied via 'modern' class.

https://jsfiddle.net/gurumvg/ubj98j6d/4/

Though the `layoutDiv` div is not having 'relative' position the `<a>` tag LOGO is positioned absolutely w.r.t `layoutDiv` div instead of BODY node. Wondering why the `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` style is positioning it as relative.

Appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the transform creates a new local coordinate system, as per [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)